# If I am unit testing what happens inside an if-clause, should I mock everything up to the if-clause?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

### The scenario

I am writing unit tests for a module similar to the one below

**service.js**

```
const client = require("./../client");

let managedData = {};

function manageData(dataId) {
  let users = client.retrieveUsers(); //Will return an array of strings. For example: a list of user names
  let user = client.retrieveCurrentUser(); //Will return a string. For example: one user name
  let userIsPresentInList = users.includes(user); //Check if the user is present in a broader user list
  if(userIsPresentInList) {
    managedData[dataId] = client.retrieveDataWithId(dataId);
  }
}


function unmanageData(dataId) {
  client.doSomethingToTheDataWithId(dataId)
  delete managedData[dataId]
}

module.exports = { 
  manageData,
  unmanageData
}
```

Some of my unit tests target what happens when the user is present in the list of users, i.e., what happens inside the if-clause

The questions is: if I am unit testing an if-clause, should I mock everything up to the clause (option 1 below)? Or should I create an way of "directly" ending up in the if-clause (option 2 below)?

### The test

**Option 1) Group the tests via describe blocks and mock in beforeEach/beforeAll:**: Scenarios that concern what's inside the if-clause are grouped in a describe block and mocks are done for all statements up until the if-clause

**Option 2) Mock intermediate functions inside module**: service.js is refactored. The code that checks whether the user is in the list of users is extracted in a new function inside the module. This function then is mocked. In this way anything before the if-clause does not really matter and the test only concerns what is inside the if-clause is working

**service.test.js**

```
const service = require("./service");
const client = require("./../client");
jest.mock("./../client");

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('Sucesful management', () => {


    //OPTION 1
    beforeEach(() => {
        client.retrieveUsers = jest.fn(() => ["a", "b", "c"]);
        client.retrieveCurrentUser = jest.fn(() => "a");
    })

    //OPTION 2
    beforeEach(() => {
        service.isUserPresentInUsersList = jest.fn(() => true);
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      service.isUserPresentInUsersList.mockRestore();
    })

    it("Given the user belongs to the user list, should retrieve the data calleing manageData", async () => {
        //Act
        service.manageData("D");
        //Assert
        expect(client.retrieveDataWithId).toHaveBeenCalledWith("D");
      });
    
      it("Given the user belongs to the user list, should do something with the data when calling unmanageData", async () => {
        //Act
        service.manageData("D");
        service.unmanageData("D");
        //Assert
        expect(client.doSomethingToTheDataWithId).toHaveBeenCalledWith("D");
      });
})
```

Is there preferable one in this case? Is any of those approaches terrible?

An extended question would be: what are open source projects that have good testing practices that I can get inspiration from?

Comment: The question has too much details. But in order to test `if`, you need to mock a condition that leads to one branch or another. If this means in your case that you need to mock the whole `client` module then that's it. *service.isUserPresentInUsersList = jest.fn* - never do anything like this. If you have a method, use jest.spyOn, it can be restored between tests.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @EstusFlask ! If I change service.isUserPresentInUsersList = jest.fn to the jest.spyOn equivalent, would mocking the service.isUserPresentInUsersList still a bad ideia? Suppose that inside the if there are calls to other functions within the module, is it better to test those functions by themselves or indirectly test it by providing the correct mocks/parameters to manageData and spy calls to them?

Comment: If this is *unit* test, it's correct to mock the most of them as they are different units. Also when you automock it like jest.mock("./../client"), all functions are already stubs, no need for jest.fn or spyOn, change their implementation with mock API where needed

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you very much for your input, I think now I have a better understanding of it. Thanks specially for the spyOn <> jest.fn input, I overlooked the documentation and didn't realize that jest.fn couldn't be restored between tests